# Why is my GoDaddy Nameservers (NH) field empty?

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, nameserver

I chose GoDaddy to host my website and I need to change the nameservers at Google Domains. GoDaddy's official guide says to follow these steps to find out your nameservers when your site is hosted by GoDaddy but the domain is registered elsewhere.

> **Find my website's nameservers**
>
> To make your website visible on the Internet, you need to point your domain name to your hosting account using nameservers. For more information, see What is DNS?
>
> This information applies only to accounts hosted with us. If you do not host with us, you can use the information in Change nameservers for my domains.
>
> Nameservers are assigned on a per-domain name basis. The same hosting account can have domain names that need to use different sets of nameservers.
>
> **Find primary domain's nameservers**
>
> 1. Log in to your GoDaddy account.
> 2. Next to Domains, click Manage.
> 3. Click the domain you want to use, and then select the DNS Zone File tab.
>
> The domain's nameservers display in the NS (Nameserver) section.
>
> Changes to your domain nameservers can take up to 48 hours to propagate.

<sup>https://godaddy.com/help/find-my-websites-nameservers-6795</sup>

I followed the instructions but my nameservers area says this:

> Nameservers
>   Last updated
>   Using hosted nameservers
>   Nameserver

with nothing next to "Last updated". Is it going to take a few hours for them to actually write my nameservers there? Or is this an error for which I'll have to contact support? GoDaddy says my site is "up and running" but it isn't because the nameservers are still pointing to my ex-host.

Comment: There is a delay in many godaddy settings becoming active.  Let's not get into a discussion on the merits (or not) of godaddy.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your reply. I'm glad I don't have a support situation on Day 1!

Answer (score 1):

The Nameservers area never updated so I called Support and told the tech it was empty. I told him the steps of their guide I followed and the tech said that it wouldn't be there (where the page led me) "It's actually outside your account". So if your Nameservers field is empty give GoDaddy a call and they'll tell you what they are. My wait time was 7 minutes.

Comment: Please do not create new accounts. Use the same account for all of your activity.